# TimeObservation in UML specification

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, specifications

In the UML specification superstructure (2.5 still Beta,page 87):

> A TimeObservation is a reference to a time instant during an execution.
>   It points out the NamedElement in the model to observe and whether the
>   observation is when this  NamedElement is entered or when it is
>   exited"

look at this example from spec.
[image]

TimeObservation is t=now

- is it possible to use another variable and where i should define those variables?
- how can specify value instead of now?
- what is the possible cases for writing timeobservation expression?
- does TimeObservation only refer to a lifeline or also refers to a message that resides between lifelines?
- If it resides through lifeline,Does this mean that it is advisable to specify it in a particular point or in any point through lifeline ?

Comment: Tried editing your question but could not understand what you are asking. Could you please specify what type of model you are creating? page of the quote from the UML specification (and version)?

Comment: @vainolo my question updated

Answer (score 1):

I agreed that more details would be useful in order to understand your question.
A TimeObservation is an UML element owned by a UML Package and related to UML NamedElement but according to its description I guess that most of the time it is associated to an Event.
So in a Sequence diagram, a TimeObservation can be related to an Occurence specification or an ExecutionSpecification i.e. the start or the end of a Message or a InteractionFragment.

Hoping it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Meta-Model Specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/SysML/20080501/UML4SysML-metamodel.xmi) states :

> A time observation is a reference to a time instant during an execution. It points out the element in the model to observe and whether the observation is when this model element is entered or when it is exited.

It refers to **any** NamedElement it annotates.

OK, I think I understand what you are trying to achieve. You are going to need to create a UML profile to do this.  Exactly how you do this will depend a lot on the tool you are using.

First Identify the UML NamedElement you want to constrain.
In the Profile add the NamedElement as a MetaClass type and extend that with your ContrainedNamedType as a StereoType.

In the profile define the Stereotype with the contraint using OCL with using the TimeObservation types.  These can be considered inherent properties.  To be fair, this is were things reach the edge of my knowledge, but Google turned up these

- [A UML Profile for Real-Time Embedded Systems](http://www-omega.imag.fr/profile.php)
- [A UML Profile for Real-Time Constraints with the OCL](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=719600)

Comment: could you please provide more clarification about quote from the UML specification?

Comment: Why do just keep posting the thing against every answer?

Comment: thank you Mr. Martin for reply i read the quote from UML specification but it is not fully elaborate for this reason i keep posting

Comment: for example timeobservation represented in sequence diagram
t=now. 
Is it possible to use another variable and where i should define those variables?
and what about "now" how can specify number instead of now?

Comment: All three responses answer your question as asked, if you need more information then go back and clarify your own question, because I don't know what or why you need clarification.

Comment: thank you for kind help.i liked to know the allowable cases to timeobservation,UML2 concept without using profile or OCL?